# Flutter Gitlab CI/CD build faild on Windows - The term 'flutter' is not recognized

Tags: flutter, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Git lab runner failed due to the error

> The term 'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program.

Flutter path is present at system variables, also restarted several times.

**The error from GitLab runner**

[image]

**The yml file**

```
deploy_android:
  dependencies:
    - flutter_build_android
  script:
    - "xxx"
    - "xxx"
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - flutter
  only:
    - master
flutter_build_android:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
  before_script:
    - "flutter pub get"
    - "flutter clean"
  script:
    - "flutter build apk --release"
  stage: build
  tags:
    - flutter
  only:
    - master
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
```

**Flutter doctor**

[image]

**Runner Config**

```
[[runners]]
  name = "name"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "xxx"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

**ENV path**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add flutter/bin folder to the environment variables:

On windows 10 click start, type environment variables, then click Edit System Environment variables

Click Environment Variables

Under User Variables, select path and click edit button

Click New and browse the path to your flutter/bin folder

Click OK

Restart your Power Shell and run flutter commands again

Comment: Flutter path is present at system variables, also restarted several times.

Comment: What does cmd say when you give "flutter --version" ?

Comment: It shows the version, you can see, flutter doctor works fine. I have attached the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix is to add flutter/bin to SYSTEM env variables.

Better fix is to specify the user to the shell executor with --user

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround and complete fix. As you know when we run command directly on the server it runs just fine but with the ci/cd pipeline it is a different story.

Problem is the user which gitlab-runner uses to run the pipeline script. This issue can be fixed just by changing gitlab-runner user.

I wrote a blog and I'm sharing the detailed guide on how to fix this.
https://thewion.com/fix-gitlab-runner-user-in-windows/